# Reduce the number of features based on feature_importances_

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have built a scikit learn random forest classifier model, and would like to reduce the number of features based on feature_importances_

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = RandomForestClassifier(5000)

model.fit(data[train], target[train])

model.feature_importances_
```

How do I subset the model so that it only includes the features identified through feature_importances_ (say the top 5 features).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 0.17 you can use [`SelectFromModel`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel)

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
model = RandomForestClassifier(5000)

new_model = SelectFromModel(model, threshold=0.5)
```

From [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_select_from_model_boston.html), there are methods to tweak the `threshold` parameter.